# UFW BLOCK port even if it is on the allow list

Tags: ufw

My relevant UFW setup is like this

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
5432                       ALLOW       Anywhere
5432 on eth0               ALLOW       Anywhere
5432 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5432 (v6) on eth0          ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

So my question is that, why the earth is [UFW BLOCK] is happening than?:

> Jan 22 06:52:35 xxx kernel: [674136.464960] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT=
>   MAC=04:01:92:0e:89:01:40:a6:77:4f:3f:f0:08:00 SRC=86.101.91.88 DST=zzz
>   LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=116 ID=780 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51046
>   **DPT=5432** WINDOW=256 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0

Really, is this some kind of rate limiter, or what... And how can I check this custom [UFW BLOCK]... or are these one time blocks?
Grrr... these things are killing me... It is generating a lots of hangs on the postgresql database....

**Edit:**
Oke, so I guess the burst settings are generating these logs, so the only quesstion now how can I change these...

> Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)  pkts bytes target     prot opt
>   in     out     source               destination  1673 81063 RETURN
>   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
>   ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10   606 29729 LOG        all 
>   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "